# Can You Use Variables This Way

Tags: c#, variables

This is my syntax, but it is not being passed to my connection string, it is being omitted, which of course is causing an error as the database doesn't exist.  Is it possible to do this?

```
namespace bottomsup
{
class onetwothree
{
    private static string databaseName = null;
    private static string ServerConnectionString = "Data Source=BradJohnson;Initial Catalog=" + databaseName + "DB;User ID = pmartin;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"";

    Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private void ConnectToServerClick()
    {
        databaseName = textbox1.Text;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ServerConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            //more stuff
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you change the value of `databaseName` later on, it doesn't automatically change the value of `ServerConnectionString`.

You have to set the value of `ServerConnectionString` again yourself.

```
ServerConnectionString =
    string.Format("Data Source=BradJohnson;Initial Catalog={0}DB;User ID = pmartin;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True", textbox1.Text);
```

I'd avoid the static variable, as it can lead to bugs if you try to reuse it, and especially if you overwrite it, in multiple places. One place sets it, then another, and now one or the other is going to grab an incorrect value when it tries to retrieve it.

Perhaps something like this instead, where you always have to pass the database name in:

```
private static string GetServerConnectionString(string databaseName)
{
    return string.Format("Data Source=BradJohnson;Initial Catalog={0}DB;User ID = pmartin;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True", databaseName);
}
```

To use it with your existing code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetServerConnectionString(textbox1.Text)))
{
    connection.Open();
    //more stuff
}
```

Comment: So I would need to re-use that same connection (of course with a diff database) multiple times in my code?

Comment: How would I implement your GetServerConnectionString method into my current syntax?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt if statics are justified in this case.

Nevertheless, it will not work with variable `ServerConnectionString`, but you could use a property instead:

```
private static string ServerConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return "Data Source=BradJohnson;Initial Catalog=" + databaseName +
          "DB;User ID = pmartin;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Often when you try to add a null value to something which has a value, it will fall over. In the DB Name you should use String.Empty as opposed to null.

Also I think you have an extra quote on the end of the string.

When you set the connection string, it is not going to dynamically update if you ever change the other property anyway.